# Choosing shutdown instead logs me out of my session

Tags: 11.04, shutdown

If I use the menu in the upper right and say shut down the computer goes to the log out screen where I then have to click in the bottom right and tell it to shut down again.

from the terminal if i say sudo poweroff it does what I would expect. Whats the deal with that?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug. I've experienced the problem as well.  Here is a bug report on the issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-session/+bug/838792